# How to redirect on first page of datatable?

Tags: php, jquery, database, datatable

I am using datatable in php.
I want to redirect on first page when doing some operation.
Right now I am using the following code but it stays on the same page where I was.

Here is the code :

```
oTable.fnClearTable();                       
oTable.fnAddData(data.aaData); 
oTable.fnDraw();
```

Any help or suggestion would be appreciate.

Comment: you need to provide more details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`page()` Since: DataTables 1.10 [Click here to refer](https://datatables.net/reference/api/page())

Get / set the current page of the table

This method provides external control over the page which the table is displaying. This can be useful if you want to provide custom paging controls for your table, external to the built-in paging control options or the paging plug-in options.

```
oTable.page( 'first' ).draw( 'page' );
```

For version 1.9.4 use

```
  oTable.fnPageChange( 'first' );
```

Comment: I am using version 1.9.4. So it is not working for me.